# Variable in file 2 is not accessible in file 1

Tags: c

My `file1.c` is as follows

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    
    return 0;
}
```

And `file2.c` is as follows

```
int x = 12;
```

When I compile both files with `gcc -std=c17 file1.c file2.c`, I get the error.

`error: ‘x’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

Now, in my `file2.c`,  `x` is a global variable. So, even if I don't declare it in `file1.c`, it should be seen in `file1.c`. So, why am I getting this error ?

Comment: reverse the order of files in the gcc command line

Comment: @jsotola, It doesn't matter. I get the same error.

Comment: There are two excellent answers below. Just to be clear, code can DECLARE a token (assigning a variable to be of a certain type like 'int' or 'double') as many times as you like with `extern`. But there can be only one DEFINITION of the token; one place in all the contributing source files where 'extern' is left off... All the declarations must be exactly the same, and the definition, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @0___________ said above you need to declare the symbol `x` so my answer is just spelling it out in a bit more detail.  It is customary to move declarations into a file2.h file so it's easy to reference in multiple places (especially if there is more than one symbol):

```
#ifndef FILE2_H
#define FILE2_H

extern int x;

#endif
```

Then modify file1.c and file2.c to include it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file2.h"

int main() {
        printf("x = %d\n", x);
        return 0;
}
```

```
#include "file2.h"

int x = 12;
```

Finally, you compile (`-std=c17` makes not difference in this sample) and link the two files.  Subsequently execute the binary::

```
$ gcc -std=c17 file1.c file2.c && ./a.out
x = 12
```

If you prefer a Makefile:

```
.PHONY: all clean
CFLAGS = -std=c17

all: a.out

clean: 
          rm -f a.out file1.o file2.o

a.out: file1.o file2.o
          $(CC) $^ -o $@

file1.o: file2.h

file2.o: file2.h
```

and it's then:

```
$ make && ./a.out
x = 12
```

Comment: why do I have include `file2.h` in `file2.c` since `file2.c` already know about the variable `x`, since its defined in that file ?

Comment: @user9026 Imagine that, inside file2.c, you accidentally defined `double x 42.567;`... The compiler needs the `.h` that is included in BOTH source files (compilation units) to verify that all is on the up-and-up across ALL the sources so the linker won't scratch its head wondering if `x` is and `int` or a `double`.

Comment: @Fe2O3, so basically, we should include `.h` file in ALL source files.

Comment: @user9026 One uses `#include <stdio.h>` so the compiler can check that `fprintf(...` or `fwrite(...` is used correctly, and that `FILE` is defined somewhere. If you write all your application code in a single `.c`, you need only those headers for 'system' stuff. If your application is in two-or-more source files, a `.h` ensures that function calls in `file1.c` match the function definitions in `file2.c`.... The common function prototype declaration is in the shared `.h`... (Your OP was an `int`, but this applies to functions too... It makes perfect sense once you see why it is done this way...

Comment: @user9026 If there are 2+ compilation units (ie. `.c` files) that should have a common understanding about data or function parameters and return types, then yes! those items of interest to BOTH compilation units should be declared in a shared `.h` file. The compiler only looks at one source file at a time. The linker joins together the compiler's `object` files to make a single executable.

Answer (score 3):

> x is a global variable. So, even if I don't declare it in file1.c, it
> should be seen in file1.c. So, why am I getting this error ?

No, code in `file1.c` does not know anything about code in the `file2.c`. Global variables are visible only in one compilation unit (ie file).

In `file1.c` you need to add (before main)

```
extern int x;
```

This declaration will tell the compiler that somewhere in the project there is a definition of the variable `x` having the type `int`

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int x;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

    printf("x = %d\n", x);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, when I add that statement, then it compiles without error. I thought that global variables are global for all files, so no need to use `extern` statement.  I was wrong.

Comment: @user9026 The downstream `link editor` will make those data items 'global' for the executable. But, the compiler looks at each source file (`.c`) separately. Each source file is called a `compilation unit`. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Fe2O3 is definitely too early.

Comment: @Fe2O3 you need to walk before you can run. The most important information is `extern`, the rest is secondary in the scope of this question